# How to download Document programmatically in SharePoint?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2007, document-library

I wanted to have a link when user clicked, it allow user to download document from SharePoint Document Library.

The link will be placed inside an aspx page.

I tried the function below:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/xls";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=abc.xls");
Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/abc.xls"));
Response.End();
```

It allow me to download the document successfully, but the downloaded document cannot open.

what is the better way to do this?

Appreciate if you could provide me some references, thank you.

Comment: What happens when you try to open the document?

Comment: What does this have to do with the title?

Comment: when I open the xls file, the error saying it is in a different format than specified by the file extension. could be my ContentType goes wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your title, Javascript can get the contents of a web.config through an XMLHTTPRequest to the server, where the server is sending that file. Of course, that's a security risk and I can't think of any reason a person would want to do that.

As for you Excel file, I would suggest using a Content-Type of "application/octet-stream" for binary responses. The browser will then simply save the binary content under the specified file name and let the program (in this case, Excel) take care of interpretting it.

Comment: Actually, by default the web.config file is not served by IIS (for those same security reasons). You could configure IIS to serve it if you really wanted to...but so not a good idea....

Comment: Brendan, 
thank you for your answer, I was entered the wrong title for this post, sorry for any inconvenience caused.